# Asynchronous command dispatch in interactive R

Tags: r, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I'm wondering if this is possible to do (it probably isn't) using one of the parallel processing backends in `R`. I've tried a few google searches and come up with nothing.

The general problem I have at the moment:

- I have some large objects that take about half an hour to `load`
- I want to generate a series of plots on the data (takes a few minutes).
- I want to go and do other things with the data while this happens (Not changing the underlying data though!)

Ideally I would be able to dispatch the command from the interactive session, and not have to wait for it to return (so I can go do other things while I wait for the plot to render). Is this possible, or is this a case of wishful thinking?

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Dirk's answer, I suggest that you use the "snow" API in the `parallel` package.  The `mcparallel` function would seem to be perfect for this (if you're not using Windows), but it doesn't work well for performing graphic operations due to it's use of `fork`.  The problem with the "snow" API is that it doesn't officially support asynchronous operations.  However, it's rather easy to do if you don't mind cheating by using non-exported functions.  If you look at the code for `clusterCall`, you can figure out how to submit tasks asynchronously:

```
> library(parallel)
> clusterCall
function (cl = NULL, fun, ...) 
{
    cl <- defaultCluster(cl)
    for (i in seq_along(cl)) sendCall(cl[[i]], fun, list(...))
    checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult))
}
```

So you just use `sendCall` to submit a task, and `recvResult` to wait for the result.  Here's an example of that using the `bigmemory` package, as suggested by Dirk.

You can create a "big matrix" using functions such as `big.matrix` or `as.big.matrix`.  You'll probably want to do that efficiently, but I'll just convert a matrix `z` using `as.big.matrix`:

```
library(bigmemory)
big <- as.big.matrix(z)
```

Now I'll create a cluster and connect each of the workers to `big` using `describe` and `attach.big.matrix`:

```
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
worker.init <- function(descr) {
  library(bigmemory)
  big <<- attach.big.matrix(descr)
  X11()  # use "quartz()" on a Mac; "windows()" on Windows
  NULL
}
clusterCall(cl, worker.init, describe(big))
```

This also opens graphics window on each worker in addition to attaching to the big matrix.

To call `persp` on the first cluster worker, we use `sendCall`:

```
parallel:::sendCall(cl[[1]], function() {persp(big[]); NULL}, list())
```

This returns almost immediately, although it may take awhile until the plot appears.  At this point, you can submit tasks to the other cluster worker, or do something else that is completely unrelated.  Just make sure that you read the result before submitting another task to the same worker:

```
r1 <- parallel:::recvResult(cl[[1]])
```

Of course, this is all very error prone and not at all pretty, but you could write some functions to make it easier.  Just keep in mind that non-exported functions such as these can change with any new release of R.

Note that it is perfectly possible and legitimate to execute a task on a specific worker or set of workers by subsetting the cluster object.  For example:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl[1], persp(big[]))
```

This will send the task to the first worker while the others do nothing.  But of course, this is *synchronous*, so you can't do anything on the other cluster workers until this task finishes.  The only way that I know to send the tasks asynchronously is to cheat.

Answer (score 4):

R is, and will remain, single-threaded.

But you can share resources.  One approach would be to load your big data in one session, assign it to a bigmemory object -- and then share the 'handle' to that object with other R sessions on the same box.  Should be a reasonably easy piece of cake on a decent Linux box with sufficient ram (ie a low multiple of all your data needs).

Comment: But you can run things on multiple processors using `foreach`? Would it be possible to write something similar that doesn't wait for the results to be returned from each process?

Comment: Go for it -- We'll be eager to test it. ;)

Comment: Well there goes my next weekend!