# Reset shiny reactive timer

Tags: r, shiny

I want to reset the reactive timer to zero and start counting to 10000 again.

If you press the reset button within 10s, "timer fires" should never print.

I thought this might work, but no.

```
require('shiny')
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("reset_button", "Reset")
  )


  server <- function(input, output) {

    autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(10000)

    observe({
      autoInvalidate()
      print ("timer fires")      

    })

    observeEvent(input$reset_button, 
     {
       autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(10000)
       print("reset")
     }
    )

  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385861/shiny-i-dont-know-how-stop-one-process-started-by-a-button-by-pressing-another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("reset_button", "Reset"),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  v <- reactiveValues(timer = Sys.time()+5)

  observe({
    invalidateLater(100)
    if(v$timer <= Sys.time()){
      v$timer <- Sys.time()+5
      print("timer fires") 
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset_button,{
    v$timer <- Sys.time()+5
    print("reset")
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This will trigger the "observe" immediately and re-execute it, also after "reset" was pressed. I am not sure what the desired behaviour should be, but I think Line 1 and 2 of OP contradict each other somehow.

Comment: This approach worked just fine for me. Maybe you're thinking of how the `observe()` is invalidated and gets reevaluated when the `v$timer` is changed using the reset button? That's true, but if the timer value is still in the future, then the `if()` condition is false, and so, nothing happens, as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I understand your desired behaviour. If you press "reset" should the timer start from 0 again, or should "timer fires" never be printed. Because with `reactiveTimer` or `invalidateLater` your code will re-execute every x milliseconds.

I came up with this little example. If you want "timer fires" never to appear when "reset" is pressed, you have to include the `loopit()` part. If you just want to reset the timer, then delete the lines with `loopit()`.

```
require('shiny')
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("reset_button", "Reset")
  )


  start = Sys.time()
  n=10000

  server <- function(input, output) {
    loopit <- reactiveVal(TRUE)

    observe({
      invalidateLater(n)
      if (loopit()) {
        print(paste("start: ", start))
        if (Sys.time() > start+(n/1000)) {
          print ("timer fires")      
        } 
      }
    })

    observeEvent(input$reset_button, {
      start <<- Sys.time()
      loopit(FALSE)
      print("reset")
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```