# Anyway to make Rshiny to halt the previous process, whenever new inputs been inserted?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rshiny

I use pickerInput inside my dashboard and the dashboard is kinda heavy and take some times to load up the data. Thus whenever i select new input from the pickerinput the Rshiny will not straightaway process the new input but finishing up the previous process first. Is there any way to make it halt the previous process?

Comment: Can you provide `ui` and `server` code required for the question to be completely reproducible along with necessary data if required?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to stop executing of R code inside shiny (without stopping the shiny process)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587883/is-it-possible-to-stop-executing-of-r-code-inside-shiny-without-stopping-the-sh)