# How to stop renderPlot from running when another renderPlot is called after a numericInput changed?

Tags: r, performance, shiny, user-input

The transitions of my Shiny app are very long when I change a `numericInput` value by clicking on the button "quickly" several times in a row .

How can I stop the previous code from running once a new `numericInput` has changed ? I don't know if I explained my problem clearly. Is it possible to put a GIF in a StackOverflow post ?

Try to play with the button to understand my problem
[image]

```r
# USER INTERFACE 
ui <-  fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(numericInput("sd", p("sd"), value = 0.1, step = 0.1)),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

# SERVER 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot<- renderPlot({
    x <- seq(-1, 1, length.out = 50000)
    plot(x, x + rnorm(50000, sd = input$sd), ylab =  "y")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30587883/4550695

Comment: @MikkoMarttila This was the first topic I found when searching the subject, but I can't find the solution that suits my simple case

Answer (score 1):

You can’t cancel a computation once it’s started without setting up some sort
of subprocess processing. However, even that would not help in this case,
because the time-consuming operation is the actual graphics rendering. You’d
need a custom equivalent to `renderPlot()` to handle that.

Likely the best you can do here is to `debounce()` the input, so that you
won’t start plotting until the input value has settled for some amount of time:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(numericInput("sd", p("sd"), value = 0.1, step = 0.1)),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  input_sd <- debounce(reactive(input$sd), 400)
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    x <- seq(-1, 1, length.out = 50000)
    plot(x, x + rnorm(50000, sd = input_sd()), ylab = "y")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Or if changing inputs too quickly is still a problem even when debounced, accept that and use a submit button to explicitly trigger the plotting.

Comment: Too bad that there is not an easy solution. I'll try to play with the parameter of `debounce` then